# Rename Docker repository

Tags: docker, docker-repository

I need to change the name of the Docker repository. For example...

ORIGINAL:

```
[root@docker ~]# docker images
REPOSITORY                              TAG                 IMAGE ID            CREATED             SIZE
registry.access.redhat.com/rhel7/rhel   latest              e64297b706b7        2 weeks ago         201MB
```

RENAMED:

```
[root@docker ~]# docker images
REPOSITORY                              TAG                 IMAGE ID            CREATED             SIZE
rhel                                    7.5                 e64297b706b7        2 weeks ago         201MB
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You do not 'rename' images. What you see in `docker images` are tags. You can add a new tag or delete one, but not 'rename'. Try tagging your image with the new tag that you want and then (optionally), delete the old tag, e.g.:

```
docker tag registry.access.redhat.com/rhel7/rhel:latest rhel:7.5
docker rmi registry.access.redhat.com/rhel7/rhel:latest # remove old tag
```